Socekt.io Issue(with typescript and react) : no data is sent with the socket, even though the connection is established
this is my backend set up for the socket.ts server
import {Server} from "socket.io"
import {createServer} from "http" 
import express from "express"

const app = express();
// Attach Socket.IO server to the HTTP server
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
cors: {
origin: "http://localhost:5173",
methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
credentials: true,
},
});

const userSocketMap: { \[key: string\]: string } = {};
export const getRecipientSocketId = (receiverId:string)=\>{
return userSocketMap\[receiverId\]
}

io.on("connection", (socket) =\> {
console.log("user connected",socket.id);

      const userId = Array.isArray(socket.handshake.query.userId) ? socket.handshake.query.userId[0] : socket.handshake.query.userId;
      if (userId !== undefined) userSocketMap[userId] = socket.id;
    
    
    
      socket.on("error", (error) => {
        console.error("Socket error:", error);
      });
      socket.on("disconnect",() => {
        console.log("user disconnected",socket.id);
        if (userId !== undefined) delete userSocketMap[userId];
      })

})

export{app, io, httpServer}


and here is where i am using it in my sendInvitaionCntroller
import User from "../../db/models/User";
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import { getRecipientSocketId, io } from "../../src/socket";

.....
// Find the sender user
const sender = await User.findById(senderId);
if (!sender) {
return res.status(404).json({
message: "Sender not found.",
data: null,
});
}
const senderUsername = sender.username;
const senderAvatar = sender.avatar;

    // Emit newNotification event with sender data
    const recipientSocketId: string | undefined =
      getRecipientSocketId(recipientId);
    if (recipientSocketId) {
      const notificationData = {
        senderId,
        recipientId,
        senderUsername,
        senderAvatar,
      };
      io.to(recipientSocketId).emit("newNotification", notificationData);


in my react app I am trying to receive the socket message here but am getting undefined and null    in the console
Header.tsx

       const [notification, setNotification] = useState<{ senderId: string, recipientId: string } |    
    
    null>(null);
    
     const { data: senderData } = useGetUserByIdQuery(notification?.senderId || '', {
      skip: !notification || !notification.senderId,
     });    
     console.log(senderData);
     useEffect(() => {
       const socket = io('http://localhost:7000'); 
    
       socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Connected to the server');
        
        socket.on('newNotification', ({ senderId, recipientId }) => {
          console.log(`New notification received. Sender ID: ${senderId}, Recipient ID:  
           ${recipientId}`);
          
          // Update the state with the new notification
          setNotification({ senderId, recipientId });
        });
        
      });
      return () => {
        socket.disconnect();
        return undefined
      }
    }, []);

Issue:
Despite correctly emitting notifications from the backend, the frontend receives undefined and null values for senderId and recipientId in the Header.tsx component.
Expected Behavior:
I expect the newNotification event emitted from the backend to contain valid senderId and recipientId values, which should be correctly received and processed in the frontend.
I would really appreciate your support, i tried to watch many videos, and different tutorials and documentations, but I dont know where is my fault yet

DId you check the socket message in Network/WS?

yes, i can see that the connection is established from ws and i can see the uid, but my I am not getting the sender data in the UI
